# Find the remainder when $x^{100}-16x^{96}+7x-3$ is divided by $x^2+x-2$

Tags: polynomials

Find the remainder when $x^{100}-16x^{96}+7x-3$ is divided by $x^2+x-2$

I'm stumped on how to find the degree of the remainder.

Comment: The degree of the remainder is $<2$ since $2$ is the degree of the divisor.

Comment: Also, there is no difficulty evaluating the polynomial at $x=1$ and $x=-2$

Comment: Do you know what a division algebra is? If not, why did you use that tag?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Since the degree of the divisor is $2$ it follows that the remainder $r$ has degree $1$ or $0$. Then, let $r(x)=ax+b$ be the remainder and denoting by $q(x)$ the quotient we have
\begin{align*}
x^{100}-16x^{96}+7x-3&=(x^2+x-2)q(x)+r(x)&&\text{Division algorithm}\\
&=(x+2)(x-1)q(x)+ax+b
\end{align*}

Now you can use the **hint** of Will Jagy in order to find $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^{100}-16 x^{96}+7x-3$. Since $g(x)=x^2+x-2=(x-1)(x+2)$ , we need to check whether $f(1)$ and $f(-2)$ equals $0$ or not.

$f(1)=-11 \neq 0$

$f(-2)=(-2)^{100}-16 (-2)^{96}-14-3=2^{100}-2^4 2^{100}-17\neq 0$

Since using division algorithm,
 $$ f(x)=g(x)p(x)+r(x) $$ where $\deg r(x)<2$. Since 
$\color{red}{\textrm{(not needed only or is sufficient) }}$
$f(1)$ and $f(-2)$ are non zero, so the degree of the remainder is $1$.

**EDIT**

Since $f(1)$ or $f(-2)$ is non zero, so the degree of the remainder is $1$.

Comment: I disagree with your logic. If $f(x)$ were a constant polynomial $\neq0$, then neither $f(-1)$ nor $f(2)$ would be equal to zero. Yet, the remainder would have degree $0$. The key to your conclusion is that $f(1)\neq f(-2)$. Then the remainder will be of degree $1$. Observe that we could even have exactly one of $f(1)$ and $f(-2)$ to be zero, and the remainder would still have degree one.

Comment: Yeah true. But for the first mistake, I am not getting how to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

using synthethic method of division,

then find the roots of the equation x^2+x-2 which are; (x-1) (x+2)
the roots are x=1 and x=-2
use p(x)=0 if and only if the roots are function of an equation
if they are not the roots then there will be a remainder